# optimize mysql taking too long

Tags: php, mysql

Today I made a clumsy update without `WHERE`. Yeah, I know.
I have backups but I found a way to fix it without loosing anything.
It implies a `SELECT` and a loop of 50.000 updates, not a fan of this approach.

Maybe I can merge the `SELECT` and the `UPDATE` so it's only a big query, witch in my head seems like a better approach.

This is table `trabajo`. One `trabajo` per row.

```
CREATE TABLE `trabajo` (
`id` INT(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`numeroEntrada` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`personaContacto` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`detallesTrabajo` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
`estadoActual` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
`importeTrabajo` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
........
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=51259;
```

This is table `tareastrabajo`. Each `trabajo` has 5 rows on `tareastrabajo`.

```
CREATE TABLE `tareastrabajo` (
`numeroEntrada` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`nombreTarea` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`fechaCompletada` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`usuario` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`descripcion` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Descripciones sobre cada fase' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`seccion` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
PRIMARY KEY (`numeroEntrada`, `nombreTarea`)
)
COMMENT='Indica las tareas que posee un trabajo'
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

In `trabajo` there's a field `numeroEntrada` that links into `numeroEntrada` in `tareastrabajo`. `tareastrabajo` saves the different status of each `trabajo` and when it changed status. To make everything easier, `estadoActual` in `trabajo` saves the current status.

The thing is I changed all the `estadoActual` to the same value. 
By checking the  last `nombreTarea` modified (checking the newest `fechacompletada`) I can get the current status.

This is the php code:

```
<?php include "inc/config.php"; ?>
<?php include "inc/funciones.php"; ?>
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>
<?php 

if(mysql_select_db($db_db2)){
    echo "connected<br>";
}

$query  = 'SELECT * FROM trabajo where estadoActual="Entrega"';
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$result = mysql_query($query);
$i = 0;
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$resultado = mysql_query($query);
try {
    while($estado = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)){

        $query  = 'UPDATE trabajo set estadoActual=(SELECT nombreTarea FROM tareastrabajo where numeroEntrada = "'.$estado["numeroEntrada"].'" AND fechaCompletada is not null order by fechaCompletada DESC limit 1) where numeroEntrada="'.$estado["numeroEntrada"].'"';
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $i++;
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo "---";
    echo mysql_error();
}
echo "<br>".$i." rows";

?>
```

witch takes 0.8 seconds per row.

DISCLAIMER: Please avoid answers and comments pointing out about mysqli or PDO. I understand the issues myself and we're in the process of migrating it. Meanwhile, we have to deal with this.

Comment: Please specify only the code's purpose in the title.  Specific requests are only needed in the post body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm blindfolded by spanish names a bit. I understood that you're trying to...

*set `tareastrabajo.nombreTarea` with newest and specified DATETIME of `tareastrabajo.fechaCompletada` into `trabajo.estadoActual` if it's value is `'Entrega'`*

If I got it right, then this single query should work:

```
UPDATE trabajo t
INNER JOIN tareastrabajo nt ON nt.numeroEntrada = t.numeroEntrada
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT numeroEntrada, MAX(fechaCompletada) AS max_fechaCompletada
    FROM tareastrabajo
    GROUP BY numeroEntrada
) tmp ON tmp.numeroEntrada = nt.numeroEntrada AND tmp.max_fechaCompletada = nt.fechaCompletada
SET t.estadoActual = nt.nombreTarea
WHERE t.estadoActual = 'Entrega'
AND nt.fechaCompletada IS NOT NULL
```

Use capital letters for query keywords and consider english names next time - (foreigners' struggle aside) it's always awkward to read them mixed with english based syntax.

Comment: I'll test that query, thanks! 
about spanish names, you're right. It's inherited code, but I should have translated it in my question. My apologies